# ASP & SQL Server 2008 : calculated value from another calculated value

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

I need to use a SQL statement that is bound to a Gridview & needs to be something like

```
SELECT * from Table Sum(Column1) AS S00, (S00/CONSTANT) AS C01 or

SELECT * from Table Sum(Column1) AS S00, Sum(Column1) / CONSTANT AS C01
```

CONSTANT will be a value passed to the query as a session variable.

i.e the 2nd column of the Gridview is calculated from the result of 1st calculation.

What will be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: It's *to calculate* or *calculation* and *calculated value* ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to repeat the expression, or use a subquery e.g.

```
SELECT *, C01 = (S00/Constant) 
FROM
(
 SELECT S00 = SUM(Column1)
  FROM table
) AS x;
```